Using python/sympy to find quadratic form of a matrix
I want to find the quadratic form of A, but what I get from $P^TAP$ is not in quadratic form:
A = Matrix([[4,4,0,-3], [4,4,3,0], [0,3,4,4], [-3,0,4,4]])

eigen_data = A.eigenvects()
eigenvectors = [vec.transpose() for val, mult, vecs in eigen_data for vec in vecs]

P = Matrix(eigenvectors).transpose()

The columns here is not unit vectors. Noting that all columns have norm $\frac{5/sqrt{2}}{3}$, I did:
PU = P/5/sqrt(2)*3

But this doesn't have just diagonal entries, so it's something that goes wrong...:
PU.transpose()*A*PU


What is a "quadratic form of a matrix"? Could you add a link with its definition/example?

Well it's actually not the matrix that is said to be in quadratic form, but it is a matrix P that will transform quadratic form equations into quadratic form equations with no cross-product terms. So that if you have a vector x and write y = Px, y will have no cross-product terms. The eigenvalues of A will be coefficients of y, and the diagnoal matrix D will be P^T A P, but in this case they don't match... so "something" is wrong...

(1) PU is not defined. (2) Are you saying you want the eigen decomposition of your matrix?

@jared (1) I thought that PU = P/5/sqrt(2)*3, and (2) yes that would be correct...

Your matrix is symmetric (so should have N orthonormal eigenvectors). However, it also has repeated eigenvalues (so the library routines won't necessarily find them - you'd have to find an orthonormal set by Gram-Schmidt or similar).
As already pointed out, this means that you can't assume P(transpose) is the same as P(inverse), and the general diagonalisation should be done with P^(-1), not P^(T).
Here with standard numpy routines:
import numpy as np

A = np.array( [ [4,4,0,-3], [4,4,3,0], [0,3,4,4], [-3,0,4,4] ] )
L, P = np.linalg.eig( A )              # columns of P are the eigenvectors

print( "Eigenvalues:", L )
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': "{:8.4f}\t".format})
print( "\nP matrix:\n", P )
print( "\nP^T A P =\n", (P.T) @ A @ P )
print( "\nP^-1 A P =\n", np.linalg.inv(P) @ A @ P )

Output:
Eigenvalues: [ 9. -1.  9. -1.]

P matrix:
 [[  0.7071    0.7071     -0.0196      0.1715   ]
 [  0.5657    -0.5657     -0.4398      0.2744   ]
 [  0.0000     0.0000     -0.7068     -0.6860   ]
 [ -0.4243     0.4243     -0.5537      0.6517   ]]

P^T A P =
 [[  9.0000   -0.0000     -0.2499      0.0000   ]
 [ -0.0000    -1.0000      0.0000     -0.2425   ]
 [ -0.2499     0.0000      9.0000     -0.0000   ]
 [ -0.0000    -0.2425     -0.0000     -1.0000   ]]

P^-1 A P =
 [[  9.0000   -0.0000      0.0000      0.0000   ]
 [ -0.0000    -1.0000     -0.0000      0.0000   ]
 [  0.0000     0.0000      9.0000     -0.0000   ]
 [ -0.0000    -0.0000      0.0000     -1.0000   ]]


Thanks! My text book didn't include any examples with repeated eigenvalues, so I overlooked that in order for the transpose to equal the inverse the matrix has to be made up of a orthonormal set of eigenvectors. But I know how to do Gram-Schmidt, so this problem is now solved!

It sounds like you are looking for the diagonalisation of the matrix:
In [22]: A = Matrix([[4,4,0,-3], [4,4,3,0], [0,3,4,4], [-3,0,4,4]])

In [23]: A
Out[23]: 
⎡4   4  0  -3⎤
⎢            ⎥
⎢4   4  3  0 ⎥
⎢            ⎥
⎢0   3  4  4 ⎥
⎢            ⎥
⎣-3  0  4  4 ⎦

In [24]: A.diagonalize()
Out[24]: 
⎛⎡4   5   4  -5⎤  ⎡-1  0   0  0⎤⎞
⎜⎢             ⎥  ⎢            ⎥⎟
⎜⎢-5  -4  5  -4⎥  ⎢0   -1  0  0⎥⎟
⎜⎢             ⎥, ⎢            ⎥⎟
⎜⎢3   0   3  0 ⎥  ⎢0   0   9  0⎥⎟
⎜⎢             ⎥  ⎢            ⎥⎟
⎝⎣0   3   0  3 ⎦  ⎣0   0   0  9⎦⎠

You can use this to express either V*D*V^-1 = A or V^-1*A*V = D:
In [25]: V, D = A.diagonalize()

In [26]: Eq(MatMul(V, D, V.inv()), V*D*V.inv())
Out[26]: 
⎡4   5   4  -5⎤ ⎡-1  0   0  0⎤ ⎡  0    -1/10   1/6   -2/15⎤   ⎡4   4  0  -3⎤
⎢             ⎥ ⎢            ⎥ ⎢                          ⎥   ⎢            ⎥
⎢-5  -4  5  -4⎥ ⎢0   -1  0  0⎥ ⎢1/10     0    -2/15   1/6 ⎥   ⎢4   4  3  0 ⎥
⎢             ⎥⋅⎢            ⎥⋅⎢                          ⎥ = ⎢            ⎥
⎢3   0   3  0 ⎥ ⎢0   0   9  0⎥ ⎢  0    1/10    1/6   2/15 ⎥   ⎢0   3  4  4 ⎥
⎢             ⎥ ⎢            ⎥ ⎢                          ⎥   ⎢            ⎥
⎣0   3   0  3 ⎦ ⎣0   0   0  9⎦ ⎣-1/10    0    2/15    1/6 ⎦   ⎣-3  0  4  4 ⎦

In [27]: V*D*V.inv() == A
Out[27]: True

In [28]: Eq(MatMul(V.inv(), A, V), V.inv()*A*V)
Out[28]: 
⎡  0    -1/10   1/6   -2/15⎤ ⎡4   4  0  -3⎤ ⎡4   5   4  -5⎤   ⎡-1  0   0  0⎤
⎢                          ⎥ ⎢            ⎥ ⎢             ⎥   ⎢            ⎥
⎢1/10     0    -2/15   1/6 ⎥ ⎢4   4  3  0 ⎥ ⎢-5  -4  5  -4⎥   ⎢0   -1  0  0⎥
⎢                          ⎥⋅⎢            ⎥⋅⎢             ⎥ = ⎢            ⎥
⎢  0    1/10    1/6   2/15 ⎥ ⎢0   3  4  4 ⎥ ⎢3   0   3  0 ⎥   ⎢0   0   9  0⎥
⎢                          ⎥ ⎢            ⎥ ⎢             ⎥   ⎢            ⎥
⎣-1/10    0    2/15    1/6 ⎦ ⎣-3  0  4  4 ⎦ ⎣0   3   0  3 ⎦   ⎣0   0   0  9⎦

In [29]: A.eigenvals(multiple=True)
Out[29]: [-1, -1, 9, 9]

I use the inverse rather than transpose because the eigenvectors in V are not unit eigenvectors. Computationally it is better for them to not be unit vectors so that all of the numbers are rational (since this matrix has rational eigenvalues).
